# How to create a postgres user that can be used by hibernate

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I have a PostgreSQL database, which I am accessing with my spring application, that uses hibernate.

For security reasons I'd like to create a user that has only the necessary right (principle of least privilege).

I couldn't find anything about the rights hibernate needs to operate.

To be a bit more specific. The user should allow hibernate to

- do CRUD operations
- create all the tables and necessary stuff I don't even know about

When I search for it, I could only find tutorials, that are using the postgres superuser or are about creating user and role entities, which have nothing to do at all with the connecting user.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate runs SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE statements. So the user will need (at least) those four privileges on the tables in question.

If the user should also create the tables, then the `CREATE` and privilege on the schema is needed.

An overview over the privilege system is available [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html) and details about each privilege are documented with the [GRANT statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html)